# Упражнение 56 Определение Частоты . Можете подсказать решение по этому заданию

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой Вариант решения о мне кажется он не корректный .

```
znak = int(input("Введите значение частоты вволны:"))

if 3 * (10 ** 9) > znak:
    print("Радиоволна")
elif 3 * (10 ** 9) == znak < 3 * (10 ** 12):
    print("Микроволна")
elif 3 * (10 ** 12) <= znak < 4.3 * (10 ** 14):
    print("Инфорокрасное излучение")
elif 4.3 * (10 ** 14) <= znak < 7.5 * (10 ** 14):
    print("Видимое илучение")
elif 7.5 * (10 ** 14) <= znak < 3 * (10 ** 17):
    print("Ультрафиолетовое излучение")
elif 3 * (10 ** 17) <= znak < 3 * (10 ** 19):
    print("Ренгенное излочение")
elif 3 * (10 ** 19) > znak :
    print("Гамма излучение")
```

Comment: и чем вам кажется это некорректным?

Comment: мне кажется что не корректно вводить цифры от пользователя . 999999999 чтобы получить гамма излучение . ну и в само задаче указано что решение будет в 31 строку по этому мне кажется что я что-то пропускаю

Comment: может требуется чтобы вы распознавали такие вещи как `"3,14 * 10^15"`?

Comment: Возможно я конечно перемудрил . решение должно быть через if elif else .

Comment: ну может имеется в виду что МАКСИМУМ 31 строка - уложились скажем в 1 строку - молодец :)

Answer (score 1):

да все нормально, но я бы переводил не в int, а во float (число с плавающей запятой):

```
znak = int(input("Введите значение частоты вволны:"))
```

тогда пользователю не надо было бы вводить `10000000000000`, он мог бы писать `1e13`

ну и проверку можно было бы тогда тоже через такую запись числа выразить (для удобства восприятия):

```
if 3e9 > znak:
    print("Радиоволна")
elif 3e9 == znak < 3e12:
    print("Микроволна")
elif 3e12 <= znak < 4.3e14:
    print("Инфракрасное излучение")
elif 4.3e14 <= znak < 7.5e14:
    print("Видимое илучение")
elif 7.5e14 <= znak < 3e17:
    print("Ультрафиолетовое излучение")
elif 3e17 <= znak < 3e19:
    print("Ренгенное излочение")
elif 3e19 > znak :
    print("Гамма излучение")
```

Ну и вообще весь код можно свернуть в такое:

```
znak = float(input("Введите значение частоты вволны:"))

waves = [(0, 3e9, "Радиоволна"), (3e9, 3e12, "Микроволна"), (3e12, 4.3e14, "Инфракрасное излучение"), (4.3e14, None, "какие-то другие волны")]

for l, r, n in waves:
    if l <= znak and (r is None or znak < r):
        print(n)
        break
```

Comment: А не будет ли удобнее заменить `None` на `float('inf')`?

Comment: ну если оно может применяться в сравнении - то конечно (я просто не в курсе был)